# Как сделать модерку на сайте

Tags: веб-программирование

Суть проблемы, есть сайт около 20 html страниц, при добавлении новой страницы приходится добавлять код на каждой страницы, что приводит определенным сложностям, связанным с пустой тратой времени. Так посоветуйте, что и как лучше сделать.

Comment: Перевести сайт на CMS?

Answer (score 1):

Собирать сайт [gulp](//gulpjs.com/)'ом, который из частей страниц будет собирать полные.
Стоит обратить внимание на плагин [gulp-inject](//www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject/).

Comment: Плюсую за грамотное решение!!)) В 2017 году как бы уже пора научиться отделять backend и frontend, а данные подтягивать через ajax, а не пихать все в "похапэ", как автор другого ответа :)

Comment: @Firepro, эм.. вообще-то мой вариант предполагает автоматическое формирование статических страниц, которые будут раздаваться севером...

Comment: Я это и имел ввиду, что не используется лишний backend, там где он уже не нужен.

Comment: @Firepro, а я почему-то про SPA подумал, когда комментарий прочитал...

Comment: Я щас перечитал свой комментарий, и эм..да..выглядит как будто замечание к ответу, но нет, это обращение к другим пользователям, что в 2017 году для формирования страниц подобного сайта можно обойтись более простыми решениями, как ваше :)

Answer (score 0):

Сделай один файл с нужным дизайном и потом с помощью PHP и функции `include` добавляй на каждую страницу его, останется только менять один файл

```php
<?php
include 'youfile.php';
?>
```